# Well water solution tank

Tags: water, well

I recently bought a home back in October of last year and everything has been running smoothly since then. The level in the solution tank goes down as it should however, when it reached the 40 mark on the tank I’m starting to get a sulfur smell from the water and my two filters don’t do much about it anymore. I’m trying to see if I can refill the solution tank after cleaning it with something else would help. I believe I have a bleach mix in there now. Any recommendations on mixtures would be appreciated. The solution tank is 100 gallons I believe.

Comment: What is a "solution tank"?

Comment: This will all depend on the exact details of what your specific treatment system is treating for, and how it's set up to do that. None of which you have shared, possibly because you don't know yourself. You need to find out.

Comment: Look for a sticker on the equipment that identifies the installer, then call them to come check out the water treatment system and have them explain how to maintain it.

Comment: Thanks I’ll look for that

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson The OP is referring to a tank holding a weak solution of bleach in water, used for oxidizing hydrogen sulfide. You and I both provided answers to a question in April, and my answer described the bleach deal. Look for the paragraph that starts *if that happens* near the bottom of this answer: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/270608/79373