# How do I get rid of a sulphur smell from my toilet & sink?

Tags: plumbing-fixture, smell

Every time I flush or run the sink I get a sulfur odor. I've only had the toilet for a year and the smell recently started.

What can I do for this?

Comment: Hydrogen Sulfide is typically a water problem, not a fixture problem.

Comment: It sounds like you own a water softening system which has failed. You should get it serviced.

Comment: If you are on private well water, your well may be contaminated with harmless but smelly sulfur bacteria. The remedy is in this answer: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/270608/79373

Answer (score 2):

I’ve seen this issue coming from 2 sources.  If you smell the rotten egg smell from all water fixtures and you are on a public water system using a well, they may have naturally occurring hydrogen sulfide in the water which is generally harmless but not desirable.  The water supplier probably strips out much of this smell with aeration and chlorination.  If their aeration system is malfunctioning you will notice the odor. You should contact them.

A second reason for the smell can be from your sewer line.  If a vent is blocked you may get some burping of air as the fluid tries to drain through the sewer line.  That can also generate a similar smell, even around the toilet if the seal is bad.

If the smell is isolated to just the two fixtures mentioned, check your sewer vents.  The p-trap should normally seal out sewer odor in your sink.  Make sure you have a trap installed.